# What is the meaning of this statement in Optics, Born-&-Wolf regarding coherence length?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, coherence

In their treatise ["*Principles of Optics*"](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781139644181.016), Max Born and Emil Wolf state in the section on coherence length (page 317, para 1) that:

> ...... as the difference of optical path is increased, the visibility of fringes decreases (in general not monotonically), and  they eventually, disappear. We can account for this disappearance of the fringes by supposing that the light of the spectral line is not strictly monochromatic, but is ***made of wavetrains of finite length*** ...........

I really can't understand what is the meaning of the emphasized line, does it refer of a light pulse of finite length, similar to a pulse going down a string (like the ones we see in video games!) or the width of the spectral line? Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... by supposing that the light of the spectral line is
> not strictly monochromatic, but is **made of wavetrains of
> finite length** ...

What the authors mean is this.
The wave actually is not an ideal sinusoidal wave of infinite length,
like this:
[image]

Instead, it is a superposition of wave packets, each

- having the same wavelength $\lambda$,
- a finite packet length $L$,
- and (most importantly) a random position
  with respect to the other packets.

(The actual shape of the wave packets is not important.
I choose Gaussian packets here for convenience.
But it could be any other shape of width $L$.)

[image]

The result of this feature is that the phase difference
between two points of the wave becomes random
when they are separated by a distance larger than $L$
(the so-called [coherence length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length)).

> ... does it refer of a light pulse of finite length, similar to a pulse
> going down a string (like the ones we see in video games!)
> or the width of the spectral line?

As explained above it refers to light pulses of finite length.
But the [coherence length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_length#Formulas) $L$ is also related
to the width $\Delta\lambda$ of the spectral line by
$$L\approx \frac{\lambda^2}{\Delta\lambda}$$

Comment: CORRECTION: [Wave packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_packet) *never* have **a** wavelength, but always consist of *infinitely many* wavelengths. Which brings us to an interesting new angle of OP's question: "Wavetrains", as dealt with in Born/Wolf, are *never* monochromatic and therefore interference fringes will *always* disappear for sufficiently large optical path length differences! And since all atomic transitions have finite time durations, *all* emission spectra are polychromatic and, therefore, of finite coherence.

Comment: This is also clear from the subsequent paragraphs in Born/Wolf, e.g. below expression (102): *"[The observed intensity] is proportional to the integral of the intensities $i(\nu) = |f(\nu)|^2$ (incoherent superposition) of the monochromatic components of which a single wave train is made up."*

Comment: Consequently, the limiting factor here isn't the coherence time/length (which is related to the spectrum, see [Wiener-Khinchin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener%E2%80%93Khinchin_theorem)), but rather the extremely short duration of said wavetrains, resulting in the superposition of wave packets of random "phases" (better: arrival times) originating from uncorrelated emission events. The term "coherence length" here is only used as an analogue to the case of continuous waves.

Comment: This is the actual explanation of the mechanism by which you get a reduction in fringe visibility given by Born/Wolf (p. 318, 2nd paragraph): *"With the interferometer, each monochromatic component produces an
interference pattern [...], and as the path difference is increased from zero, these component patterns show **increasing mutual displacement because of the difference of wavelength**. The visibility of the fringes therefore decreases, and
they disappear altogether when the optical path difference is sufficiently large."*

Comment: Important: The ***"difference of wavelength"*** here refers to the **individual Fourier components** of each individual wave packet! Each Fourier component individually interferes with its own copy upon traveling along both interferometer arms and produces a corresponding fringe pattern (Born/Wolf: *"each monochromatic component produces an interference pattern..."* and *"the longer the wave trains, the narrower the frequency range over which the Fourier components have appreciable intensity"*). ...

Comment: (Note that two waves with differing frequencies can absolutely never produce static fringes as can be easily simulated using e.g. two point sources and observing the resulting wave field! This is an important point as we can discard any pairs of Fourier components with differing frequencies, since they produce zero fringe visibility over any practical observation times.)

Comment: ... The real crux in understanding/comprehending the explanation by Born/Wolf (i.e. on p. 318, 2nd paragraph as cited above) is **how exactly** the *difference* with which the individual *"[Fourier] component patterns"* get displaced with increasing optical path length difference results in a reduction in fringe visibility. I think a series of simulations/visualizations is required to really wrap one's head around this mechanism. Especially since the situation in real life is quite complicated, i.e. the fringe visibility oftentimes *does not decay monotically* as you already cited:

Comment: *"as the difference of optical path is increased, the visibility of fringes decreases (**in general not monotonically**), and they eventually, disappear"*. This question, concerning the detailed mechanism of decoherence, has IMHO not been explained on SE yet and is topic of an [ongoing discussion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/748947/what-is-a-good-coherence-correlation-function-for-multimode-spectra).

Comment: To explain it more simply, consider once more the "explanation" by Born/Wolf as cited above: *"as the path difference is increased from zero, these component patterns show increasing mutual displacement because of the difference of wavelength. The visibility of the fringes **therefore** decreases, and they disappear altogether when the optical path difference is sufficiently large."* - To me, it is not at all clear, how this *"therefore"* actually comes about. ...

Comment: ... Think about it: Born/Wolf are concerned with **single-frequency Fourier components** (see above). However, the waves corresponding to such Fourier components have, as per mathematic definition of plane waves, **infinite spatiotemporal extent**! An increase in optical path length difference would, therefore, not cause a monotonic decay in fringe visibility, but rather an undamped, **periodic** oscillation. So this decay in fringe visibility results from a superposition of gradually shifted fringe patterns - not waves/wave packets - starting from zero shift (where maximum contrast is...

Comment: ...observed), towards more and more displacement, for which according to the cited explanation in Born/Wolf a gradual (but not necessarily monotonic) decay in visibility should be observable. However, to actually understand this situation, a simulation/visualization would be necessary to demonstrate the effect.